# Unable to connect to the azure container Instance after deploying to ContainerGroup

Tags: azure-container-service, azure-container-registry, azure-container-instances

I am trying to deploy a Java Web application into the Tomcat Container 
 `docker run -d -p 8080:8080 java-app` , the Java Web application was up and running onto the my local like http://localhost:8080/sample. 
When I tried to push this image to the Azure and then it gives me public IP address , but it says unable to connect or connection refused . I checked the logs it says .war file deployment done. I have created a network security group also and kept inbound rules to open every port.

http://40.83.211.81:8080/sample

unable to connect

Please anyone can help me for these. Thanks

Comment: is it possible your local firewall is blocking port 8080?

Comment: Thankyou for help @Sorceri , it was not a issue with firewall.

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved these issues , whenever you try to deploy to the Azure , you should specify `--port` parameter and default is 80. So in my case is 8080.

`az container create --name java-app1 --image <acrLoginServer>/java-app:v1 --cpu 1 --memory 1 --registry-password <yourServerPassword> --port 8080 --ip-address public -g myContainergroup`.

Now it is up and running on to the public IP address.

Comment: Have a similar issue, what about port 443 or 80? there you just expose 8080 whic is already exposed on dockerfile when you run EXPOSE 8080.
I created the instance and I´m unable to telnet the public ip that azure provides.
thanks!